# An unknown user profile error has occurred

Tags: 2007, my-site

Full error

> An unknown user profile error has occurred. Try recreating this user profile or updating the user profile from the directory service to resolve this problem

This error has appeared on all profiles when edits are being attempted. No settings have been changed in SharePoint that I am aware of.

Unfortunately I do not know much about the back end setup of our SharePoint as I only support the front end such as, creating sites, granting permission and editing users MySites when they have issues. I do have access to Central admin and the server. The system was also already setup when I took over support.

If more information is required to answer this question I will do my best to provide it.

SharePoint Search has also stopped working if that is related.

Comment: do you have access to the Server & central admin? Looks Like SSP went down.

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE I do have access. I added that I do into the question.

Comment: check this one https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/3e774f06-2bed-4fbf-862a-f772aeee8e77/an-unknown-user-profile-error-has-occurred-try-recreating-this-user-profile-or-updating-this-user?forum=sharepointgenerallegacy

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE it seems the AD group we use to grant permissions does not have the manager User Profiles right but has Personal Features and Personal Site. Wouldn't granting Manage User Profiles allow anyone to update any site?